# I am unable to run r307 fingerprint sensor, nor rp203 , nor sd card reader via Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, fingerprint

I have tried and used newest to older versions of arduino ide but with no success. I am using Adafruit libraries for fingerprint and thermal printer. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days of trying each and everything, finger print module finally worked by changing baud rate from 57600 to 115200